# Django - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, get, httprequest

I'm having a problem coding this:
1. my web page sends request to the server with parameter X which is a URL
2. server gets X and opens a new connection to X and get data from there
3. server sends a response to my webpage with the retrieved data

I send the request with JS get. The problem is that once the server gets the request and open the new connection to X it drops the connection to my webpage.

I'm using Django, as I understand it can only handle one request at a given time.

inside document ready is the sending the request:

```
$("#valid").click(function(){

        $.get("/extract/validate_xpath", {url:document.getElementById('v_url').value,
            query:document.getElementById('v_query').value} ,function(data, status){
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
        });

    });
```

here is the Django view that suppose to handle the request:

```
def validate_xpath(request):
  dic=request.GET.copy()
  data = urlopen(dic['url']).read()
  tree = etree.HTML(data)
  response = tree.xpath(dic['query'])
return HttpResponse(dumps(response))
```

the error occurs on

> urlopen(dic['url']).read()

the error I get:

```
    [29/Dec/2017 12:06:20] "GET /static/extract/help.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
8000
http://shut.moreshet.co.il/advancedSearchResult.asp?i=0&nop=20&WholeWord=0&aw=&shut=&rabonim=  //a[@class = "text16bold"]/@href
<class 'str'>
[29/Dec/2017 12:06:27] "POST /extract/validate HTTP/1.1" 200 1660
[29/Dec/2017 12:06:44] "GET /extract/validate_xpath?url=http%3A%2F%2Fshut.moreshet.co.il%2FadvancedSearchResult.asp%3Fi%3D0%26nop%3D20%26WholeWord%3D0%26aw%3D%26shut%3D%26rabonim%3D&query=%2F%2Fa%5B%40class%20%3D%20%22text16bold%22%5D%2F%40href HTTP/1.1" 200 135
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 252, in send_preamble
    self._write(('HTTP/%s %s\r\n' % (self.http_version,self.status)).encode('iso-8859-1'))
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[29/Dec/2017 12:06:44] "GET /extract/validate_xpath?url=http%3A%2F%2Fshut.moreshet.co.il%2FadvancedSearchResult.asp%3Fi%3D0%26nop%3D20%26WholeWord%3D0%26aw%3D%26shut%3D%26rabonim%3D&query=%2F%2Fa%5B%40class%20%3D%20%22text16bold%22%5D%2F%40href HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59412)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 252, in send_preamble
    self._write(('HTTP/%s %s\r\n' % (self.http_version,self.status)).encode('iso-8859-1'))
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 88, in handle_error
    super(ServerHandler, self).handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 639, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 155, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
```

any workaround to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: what's your code for getting X and opening the connection to X? Are you using any library?

Comment: I get X as a string and then trying to use urllib read method

Comment: We need some code to help you. There's no reason the connection should drop, unless you have short timeout

Comment: edited the question - added the code.
like I mentioned, it gets URL and XPATH query and suppose to use URLLIB to run the query on that URL and return the answer.

Comment: you say there's an error, is django actually producing one? If so, can you also show that?

Comment: added the error

Comment: I usually use the `requests` library to make these kind of 3rd party API requests. e.g. `response = requests.get(dic['url'], timeout=2)\n data = response.json()`.

Comment: although it's not clear to me that the error is happening during the `urlopen` or after. Are you sure there's no response sent back? `response = urlopen(dic['url'])` (before doing `read()`)?

Comment: tried using requests.get like you suggested, still getting the same error.. same for urlopen (without read)